# How To Implement imhmin() in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, non-maximum-suppression

I would like to implement imhmin() function of matlab in c++.  Firstly, I have examined the algorithm. It suppresses the minimum pixel intensity values. Non-maximum suppression code is:

```
void non_maxima_suppression(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& mask, const bool remove_plateaus)
{
    // find pixels that are equal to the local neighborhood not maximum (including 'plateaus')
    cv::dilate(src, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::compare(src, mask, mask, cv::CMP_GE);

    // optionally filter out pixels that are equal to the local minimum ('plateaus')
    if (remove_plateaus) {
        cv::Mat non_plateau_mask;
        cv::erode(src, non_plateau_mask, cv::Mat());
        cv::compare(src, non_plateau_mask, non_plateau_mask, cv::CMP_GT);
        cv::bitwise_and(mask, non_plateau_mask, mask);
    }
}
```

imhmin() function returns suppressed values. However, non-maximum suppression returns binary values. How can I handle it?

Comment: First of all, you should give a detailed explanation of imhmin. Second, you should explain the relation between non-maximum suppression and imhmin. Third, if i got it correct, just find the smallest value `min`, then change any value to `h+min` which is smaller than `h+min`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the result you get as mask for source image.